# How can I make an image of my Vaio/Windows 8bootable USB recovery disk?

Tags: backup, bootable-media

I have created a USB recovery disk for my Vaio running Windows 8, using the Vaio Care tool (so it's got all its drivers and bloatware etc included).

I'd like to be able to reclaim the USB stick and put the contents of it onto my backup HDD so that it can be 'burned' to the USB stick at a later time, if required.

From what I've read so far, this process isn't as straight-forward as creating an ISO and then burning it back to disk because the bootable data isn't included in the ISO.

What do I need to do to be able to successfully backup the USB recovery disk and recreate a bootable version of it again in future?

Comment: Just copy all the files off, when you are ready to make the usb stick again, just [format it and make it bootable](http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/2/), then copy the files back.

Comment: [Or make an ISO image of the drive](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/create-iso-image-of-usb-flash-drive.301882/)

Comment: My understanding is that that approach won't make copies of the bootable part of the system.

Comment: I have done it, it works. did you read my first link I posted above?

Comment: Yes, I've read it and a few others like it. I can't find the guides I'd read mentioning that the bootable part doesn't get read and included in the ISO, otherwise I'd post it here. I'll give your method a try - no harm done by trying it.